# scrolling and pan/zoom in single scene cocos2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am currently working on my first IOS app and have sort of hit a 'brick wall' if you will. I am using Cocos2D for most of my graphical interface do to my preference and ease when working with chipmunk.

Currently I am trying to create a scene that has at least 2 layers displayed at once, split screen style. One layer I need to be a vertical scrolling menu, while the other layer I need to be a pan/zoom 'map' type layer. Being the noob that I am when it comes to Objective-C and Cocos2D I can not seem to figure out how to even attempt this. I have done some searching and came across the extensions for Cocos2D which offer the pan/zoom layer.

Any help or pointers to tutorials, references, sites, etc. would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very broad question that covers a lot of topics, if you want to get the best answers I suggest focusing on maybe one thing at a time.